# NASM modifying a string

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm new to using Assembly (all types), so I was following tutorials from tutorialspoint.com
In particular, I was on the page https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_addressing_modes.htm which is about Assembly Addressing. Everything was working, up until the final example where it gave the code (takes the name Zara Ali and changes it to Nuha Ali):

```
section .text
   global _start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start:             ;tell linker entry point

   ;writing the name 'Zara Ali'
   mov  edx,9       ;message length
   mov  ecx, name   ;message to write
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

   mov  [name],  dword 'Nuha'    ; Changed the name to Nuha Ali

   ;writing the name 'Nuha Ali'
   mov  edx,8       ;message length
   mov  ecx,name    ;message to write
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

   mov  eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
name db 'Zara Ali', 0xa
```

This code works of course, however, when modifying it slightly, I ran into problems. In line 13, I changed 'Nuha' to 'Nuhas' just to see if it would come up with 'NuhasAli' (since I'm assuming that that line is just replacing whatever bits are there with Nuhas and keeping the rest (Ali)).

When I tried this and ran the command 'nasm -f elf helloasm.asm' (helloasm.asm is the name of the file), it gave me these two messages:

```
helloasm.asm:13: warning: character constant too long
helloasm.asm:13: warning: dword data exceeds bounds
```

I couldn't find any insight into the first problem as when I looked it up, all it gave me were results regarding C and C++. However, as for the second warning, I tried to make the dword data stop exceeding the bounds by simply making it a qword instead of a dword

```
section .text
   global _start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:             ;tell linker entry point

   ;writing the name 'Zara Ali'
   mov  edx,9       ;message length
   mov  ecx, name   ;message to write
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

   mov [name], qword 'Nuhas'    ; Changed the name to Nuha Ali

   ;writing the name 'Nuha Ali'
   mov  edx,10      ;message length
   mov  ecx,name    ;message to write
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

   mov  eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
    name dw 'Zara Ali', 0xa
```

```
helloasm.asm:13: warning: character constant too long
helloasm.asm:13: error: operation size not specified
```

At this point, I was stumped.
Can anyone offer any insight into why this is happening and how I should fix it? Are my fundamentals wrong? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mov  [name],  dword 'Nuhas'` fails because a `DWORD` is four bytes long, but `Nuhas` is five bytes long.  There is nothing strange about that, the assembler is telling you precisely what is wrong, and it even says it in two different ways: "character constant too long" and "dword data exceeds bounds".  You just can't fit 5 bytes into a place that can only hold 4 bytes.

`mov [name], qword 'Nuhas'` fails apparently because `name` is a `DWORD`, not a `QWORD`, and if you somehow managed to shoehorn 8 bytes into it you would probably be corrupting the memory immediately following it.

**EDIT**

I guess the confusion stems from the fact that the sample code you found has `name dw 'Zara Ali', 0xa`, which is perhaps making you believe that you can fit that entire text in a `DWORD`.  I don't know why they used `dw`, it seems to me that they should have used `db`.  The only reason why they were able to do that is because the assembler allows this kind of hack, but in order for their sample code to be understandable and intuitive, they should have used `db`, because that's what you are declaring there: a sequence of bytes.

In any case, the `dw` directive has nothing to do with the `mov [name], dword 'wxyz'` instruction.  The `dw` directive is declaring an arbitrary-length sequence of `DWORD`s. The `mov` instruction can copy a fixed amount of bytes: either a single byte, or two bytes (a `WORD`) or four bytes (a `DWORD`).  (Or perhaps even eight bytes, a `QWORD`, if there are any instructions that can somehow specify a quad-word operand, though I cannot think of any right now.)  The assembler probably performs some rudimentary type checking, making sure that the target quantity is of a type suitable to receive the source quantity, and the check passes, since `name` has been defined with `dw`, and the quantity being stored is given as a `DWORD`.

So, the `mov [name], dword 'wxyz'` instruction is actually a hack: it packs the four characters you gave it into a DWORD, and stores that in `[name]`.  `name` has been defined with `dw`, so it is of the correct type, so the hack works.  However, only four characters can be packed in a DWORD, that's why 'Nuhas' does not work.  Also, you cannot do `name dq 'bla bla bla'` and expect `mov [name], qword 'wxyzwxyz'` to work, because there is no instruction that will move an immediate qword, since the instruction set that you are working with is 32-bit.  (You could do that with a 64-bit instruction set.)

Comment: You might mention the solution, which is to split the write to memory up into multiple bits, each a maximum of 4 bytes in length. The `name` variable is 9 bytes long; it has enough room.

Comment: The first part makes sense to me, but as for the second part, why is name only 4 bytes long since I managed to put Zara Ali in it which should mean that it is 8 bytes (or 9 as @CodyGray just said) and should have enough space to fit a qword which is also 8 bytes

Comment: It's 9 bytes, the last byte is `0xa`. You can't move a QWORD at a time on a 32-bit system. You have to move 2 DWORDs. Little endian, of course. @eames

Comment: Ah okay that's what I was looking for, but how do I split the memory? Is there a command for that?

Comment: You don't need to "split the memory". I don't even know what that means. You just write 2 DWORDs: `mov DWORD [name], lowDword` followed by `mov DWORD [name+4], highDword`.

Comment: Yea, that's what I meant, but does that mean I would have to declare 'lowdword' and 'highdword' in 'section .data' like "low db 'nuha'" and "high db s, 0xa"because if I do, I've really been taking primitive type casting in higher level languages for granted

Comment: @Eames with Cody Gray's suggestion you should not have to change the 'dw' into 'db'.

Comment: Oh gosh, I didn't even notice that the string was declared as an array of *words*! Silly me. Probably whoever wrote that code was programming for Windows, where the platform's of Unicode strings is UTF-16, where each character is a WORD in length. I'd upvote this answer because of the edit, but I can only upvote once. :-) Anyway, in answer to your question, @eames, no, you wouldn't need to declare `loWord` variables. In fact, you *can't*, because you can't have two memory operands. They should be *constants*, like multi-character literals. All you're doing is treating `name` like an *array*.

Comment: Also, in contrast to MASM, [NASM does not do type checking](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/mp/f99/mp5/masm_nasm.html).

Comment: Actually, @CodyGray, I think that the array still consists of 8-bit characters.  I think that the only usefulness of `dw` is to allow addressing two characters at a time using a 16-bit register.

Comment: It's all in how you look at it. From the assembler's perspective, *everything* is just bytes. So yeah, you can pack 2 BYTEs in a WORD. Or you can put a single WORD in  a WORD.

Comment: Well, anyway, for anyone interested, int 80h, function 4 appears to be linux sys_write(), take a look at this: http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html (it makes use of `db` instead of `dw`.)